# Averageif Function

Tags: excel, function, average

I'm trying to get an Average If function to work, the basis is this.

```
Sheet 1
    TIME               Duration (sec)
    4/24/2013 5:04     57
    4/24/2013 5:09     122
    4/25/2013 12:22    341

Sheet 2
    Date           Average Duration
    4/24/2013      
    4/25/2013
```

My question I have right now is what should the function for average duration be?

I have something like this:

```
=AVERAGEIF('Sheet1'!C:C,SEARCH("4/24/2013", 'Sheet1'!C:C))
```

Column C in sheet 1 is the date, Column D is the duration

Comment: Are the dates in column C real dates or stored as text? A pivot table would be simpler if it's an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you exactly what you are looking for and it will disregard the times so that you can search by an entire day regardless of time. Please remember to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter when putting this equation in as it is an array equation.

```
=SUM(IF(TEXT(DateSearchRange,"m/dd/yy")=TEXT(DateSearchingCell,"m/dd/yy"),DurationRange,0))/SUM(IF(TEXT(DateSearchRange,"m/dd/yy")=TEXT(DateSearchingCell,"m/dd/yy"),1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to insert a helper column, between the present C and D, with =LEFT(C2,5) copied down (assuming `57` is in Row2 and Date is in ColumnA) the formula you tried should work as adapted:

> =AVERAGEIF(Sheet1!D:D,A2,Sheet1!E:E)

=SEARCH is not suitable for the condition because it returns the position of one string within another and the second C:C pair would be trying to average TIME, rather than Duration.